# JSON of Wikipedia table data not on Wikidata or DBpedia, next steps?

Tags: json, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'd like to have the giant table from [Wikipedia's List of Freedom Indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_freedom_indices#cite_ref-FreedomInTheWorld_10-0) as a JSON.

I don't think this table information is on Wikidata or DBpedia.

What would be a next step? Using the REST API? If so, can you suggest the first step in doing that?

Or doing something with the URL, like (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=List_of_freedom_indices&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json)? If this is the right way of going about it, how might I get just the table? [Here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) I don't see any option for returning only table data.

Comment: If you downvote, please tell me why, so I can improve my questions in future!

Comment: I take it you mean the 'list by country'? Because your link goes to a citation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> only table data

```
&section=
```

See

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&page=List_of_freedom_indices&section=3
```

or just plain text

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=raw&title=List_of_freedom_indices&section=3
```